# I can't do click to div has been within div with slideDown. jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this page http://nelsonpatojimenez.com/startupchile.org/joinastartup/, but when I try to click in "be part of it" callback to slideDown function.

This code hide and show the jobs when you click in the startup

```
    $('section.listjobs').on('click', '.jobgroup', function(e){
            var classes = $(this).attr('class');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if ($(this).children(':last').hasClass('hidedescription')) {
                $(this).children().slideDown('slow').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidedescription');
                $(this).css('border-bottom','0px');
            }else{
                var div = $(this).children(':last');
                var divdiv = div.children(':last');
                var divdivdiv = divdiv.children(':last');

                $(this).children(':last').slideUp('slow').addClass('hidedescription');
                $(this).css('border-bottom','1px dashed #0071A0');
            };          
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

I need that when I clck in "be part of it", this goes to the next page.

Any idea?

Comment: Try putting an `alert('im here');` before `var classes = ...` just to make sure the function is even being called.

Comment: Yes this called the funciton, but I need that when clicked "be part of it" this call href, i don't want to calling slideDown in this moment :/

Answer (score 0):

The proble was I have this line in the end.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

When delete this line, href sent me to next page.

:D, thanks a lot for your answers.